# XCUITest pass arguments to the test

Tags: xcodebuild, xcuitest, xctestcase

i have an app that can show many popups in various scenarios, and i would like to verify their text using XCUITest. but would like to be able to do that with no effort for multiple text configurations. for multiple languages for instance.

Is there a way to pass arguments through the .xctestrun file or through the "xcodebuild test-without-building" command? some way to pass the dictionary, or a file that i can parse at the beginning of the `XCTestCase` to know the correct text values to predict? preferably without the need to rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.
The test host (and your `XCTestCase`s) can view its arguments same as the test target, using `NSProcessInfo.processInfo.environment` and `NSProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments`.

Using the scheme for "Test" in XCode, you can add arguments and environment variables that the test host itself can read. The test host can read these by using the process info as mentioned above.

Another way to do this would be by editing the xctestrun file for your test. In it, you can add the key `CommandLineArguments` as an array of strings for the process info arguments, or add `EnvironmentVariables` as a dictionary from key to string value.
An easy way to go about adding the arguments/variables to the xctestrun file manually would be to first add them to the Test scheme in XCode, see the changes to the xctestrun file, and modify them accordingly.

other xctestrun variables are described in https://www.manpagez.com/man/5/xcodebuild.xctestrun/

Comment: Same method, even simpler: launch arguments appear as UserDefaults variables.